# Couchbase getting data from nested documents

Tags: .net, couchbase

We are trying to learn and implement couchbase in one of our projects, and what we are trying to have is a nested document which looks like this

```
{{"type": "CommonConfi", "Styles": ["id_1", "id_2"]}}
```

and `id_1` and `id_2` are different documents, which are referred in the first document

While trying to get data using the couchbaseclient API for .NET which operation will help us get data.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Couchbase .NET SDK, which is 2.1.1 at the moment, this is how you would get the top level document as well as the nested child documents:

```
var doc = await bucket.GetAsync<Parent>("docid");                   // Get the top-level document
var operations = doc.Value.Styles.Select(bucket.GetAsync<Child>);   // Launch tasks to get child docs concurrently
var results = await Task.WhenAll(operations);                       // Wait for all tasks to complete
var childDocs = results.Where(r => r.Value != null).Select(r => r.Value); // Extract the child documents
```

This example assumes that the parent and child documents are represented by the `Parent` and `Child` classes, respectively.